# Anaconda Jupyter Lab on Remote Server: Permission Error

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-lab

The error is the following:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/.jupyter/jupyter_no                                                                                                                                                             tebook_config.json'

Related Questions are :
[Jupyter notebook permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878178/jupyter-notebook-permission-error)
[Could not install packages due to a "Environment error :[error 13]: permission denied : 'usr/local/bin/f2py'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807507/could-not-install-packages-due-to-a-environment-error-error-13-permission-d)

Machine - Ubuntu 16.04, Conda installed.

I get that I don't have root on this remote server - But perhaps I can have root if I use the right command.

Note the jupyter lab command is trying to access a non conda install of jupyter lab (config file /home/ubuntu/.jupyter). I want to access the conda install from the folder anaconda 3 installation- see the full error for reference. Any suggestions/ideas would be most welcome and will receive a surprising number of hail marys. Thanks for looking.Alternatively, maybe I can find some way to point jupyter -lab to the conda config.

Full Error

```
    ubuntu@96-76-203-14:~$ jupyter lab
[E 00:58:14.174 LabApp] Exception while loading config file /home/ubuntu/.jupyte                                                                                                                                                             r/jupyter_notebook_config.json
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/                                                                                                                                                             application.py", line 562, in _load_config_files
        config = loader.load_config()
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/                                                                                                                                                             loader.py", line 406, in load_config
        dct = self._read_file_as_dict()
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/                                                                                                                                                             loader.py", line 411, in _read_file_as_dict
        with open(self.full_filename) as f:
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/.jupyter/jupyte                                                                                                                                                             r_notebook_config.json'
[I 00:58:14.188 LabApp] The port 7000 is already in use, trying another port.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/applicat                                                                                                                                                             ion.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/appl                                                                                                                                                             ication.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/appl                                                                                                                                                             ication.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.                                                                                                                                                             py", line 1299, in initialize
    self.init_server_extensions()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py"                                                                                                                                                             , line 209, in init_server_extensions
    super(LabApp, self).init_server_extensions()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.                                                                                                                                                             py", line 1258, in init_server_extensions
    section = manager.get(self.config_file_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/con                                                                                                                                                             fig/manager.py", line 25, in get
    recursive_update(config, cm.get(section_name))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/mana                                                                                                                                                             ger.py", line 62, in get
    with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/.jupyter/jupyter_no                                                                                                                                                             tebook_config.json'
```

**Update:**

So I just tried jupyter notebook instead , and that worked but does not show me the token just three dots in a strangely mysterious fashion... (yes exactly like that)

```
ubuntu@96-76-203-14:~/anaconda3$ jupyter notebook
[I 01:41:12.637 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/not                                          ebook_cookie_secret
[I 01:41:12.649 NotebookApp] The port 7000 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 01:41:12.653 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3
[I 01:41:12.654 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 01:41:12.654 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://0.0.0.0:7001/?token=...
[I 01:41:12.654 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice                                           to skip confirmation).
[W 01:41:12.654 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
^C[I 01:41:25.822 NotebookApp] interrupted
Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3
0 active kernels
The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://0.0.0.0:7001/?token=...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this folder and check. Sometimes this solves the permission issue

```
'/Users/ArcherWoo/.jupyter
```

Also, Try to Run jupyter from a subdirectory and not the root of your home directory.

Add don't forget to give permissions [chmod  777](https://blog.csdn.net/sudakuang/article/details/78298320) to the directory

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/home/ubuntu/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py': Permission denied . How do I get permission for that?