# #Python importing data --Alex the analyst project

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror, permission-denied, permissionerror

I am working on Python /data analysis portfolio watching Alex the Analyst youtube video.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocdwh0KYeUs&list=PLUaB-1hjhk8H48Pj32z4GZgGWyylqv85f&index=5)

However the code he provided does not work whats so ever.
I tried this code $ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=""(found at: [Jupyter notebook permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878178/jupyter-notebook-permission-error)) but this did not work either.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab 
import matplotlib 
plt.style.use('ggplot') 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure 
%matplotlib inline 
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,8) 
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\enana\Downloads\movies.csv')
```

I am just trying to follow along while I do this project, so I don't really understand what is going on above. And I don't know what is happening when I return this code which is as follows:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18392/3202830863.py in <module>
     16 
     17 # Now we need to read in the data
---> 18 df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\enana\Downloads\movies.csv')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    585 
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    587 
    588 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    480 
    481     # Create the parser.
--> 482     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    483 
    484     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    809             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    810 
--> 811         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    812 
    813     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1038             )
   1039         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1040         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1041 
   1042     def _failover_to_python(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
     49 
     50         # open handles
---> 51         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
     52         assert self.handles is not None
     53 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
    220         Let the readers open IOHandles after they are done with their potential raises.
    221         """
--> 222         self.handles = get_handle(
    223             src,
    224             "r",

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    700         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    701             # Encoding
--> 702             handle = open(
    703                 handle,
    704                 ioargs.mode,

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\enana\\Downloads\\movies.csv'
```

Please help.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083806/permissionerror-permission-denied-to-reading-csv-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following: While dealing with such problem, we need to understand path we provided it should be with double "\".

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\enana\\Downloads\\movies.csv")
```

Your problem may get solved.